# Notification, keyboard hide

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    keyboardUpNotification()
    keyboardDownNotification()
}

func keyboardUpNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    print("keyboard up notification registered")
}
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y = 0 - keyboardSize(notification)
    print("keyboard will show method. \(keyboardSize(notification))")
}


func keyboardDownNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    print("keyboard down notification registered")
}
func keyboardWillHide() {
    print("keyboard will hide method")
    view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

I add two notifications( keyboard up, down ). I want the keyboard hide when I touch a return button. But keyboardWillHide() method is not calling. What did I wrong or missed?

Comment: Show `keyboardWillShow` method also.

Comment: are you enabled the delegate for your text fiedl

Comment: I just added keyboardWillShow method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first

1.Make your ViewController to confirm textField delegate

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

2.Set self as textField delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.yourTextField.delegate = self
}
```

3. Implement

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: @y-kim : Am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UITextField, set delegate and override this method:

```
optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

This method gets called when the return key is hit. Then you call

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

Then the keyboard will be dismissed.